# Creating dependency between two xcframeworks without adding direct imports

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have this kind of structure for my frameworks,

[image]

Now I want to access some methods in Framework B to Framework A, without creating a direct dependency between these two frameworks. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Another framework? Sort of a proxy or facade for B.